# Is there such a thing as a moral statement?

Tags: metaethics, logical-positivism

Logical positivists, notably A.J. Ayer, have stated that there is no such thing as a moral statement. In his example, saying the words "you acted wrongly in stealing that money" are semantically equivalent to saying "you stole that money".

I cannot find anything unsound with the structure of the argument, but I would not readily like to accept its conclusion. Is there anything that has been done to rescue the (if at least somewhat) objective reality of certain morally evaluative statements?

Comment: Emotivism and prescriptivism did not go quite so extinct as logical positivism overall did, but one key argument against those positions is the argument from disagreement. Now with ethical subjectivism, we often say that *X is good* translates to *I approve of X*, which can be true even if someone else disapproves of X. And, "Hooray for X!" and, "Hooray for ~X!" (or "~Hooray for X!") are that approval itself, not just reports of it. They conflict, but is that enough to satisfy the disagreement intuition? Which is that people genuinely disagree about moral claims.

Comment: Parallelwise, however, consider [quasi-realism in ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-realism), which is non-cognitivist (or, better, quasi-cognitivist), which recovers more of the disagreement intuition (grounding the intuition also in an appeal to [moral supervenience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_supervenience)).

Comment: Finally, consider higher-order ethical statements, like, "Goodness is a function of rightness," or, "Rightness is a function of goodness," or, "There is a difference between [thin and thick moral concepts](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/thick-ethical-concepts/)," &c. Now I expect that these can be parsed in quasi-/non-cognitivist ways by the by but eventually we'll start mutating our subcognitivism into ethical subjectivism, which can easily evolve back into a more objective realism if its life depends on it (e.g. by noting that almost nothing is totally subjective *or* objective).

Comment: There may not be objective moral proposition as some descriptive truth bearer, but there're definitely unambiguous, sometimes detailed stipulated complex ethical statements implemented as various compliance codes in almost every organization in most societies to address some pertinent practical issues such as conflict of interest, bribe, coordination, etc...

Comment: Perhaps it would be more effective to move towards agreement instead of entrenching disagreement? Perhaps 'moral' could be redefined as: "This has been shown to work well, and we all agree on it. " Rewrite Morality in terms of *Engineering.* In that case, it is always assumed that one's definitions and procedures will inevitably improve. They are absolutely subject to change.

Comment: @ScottRowe, it would be better for me to avoid trying to entrench disagreement, yes. Unfortunately, "we all agree on it" will be difficult to cash out; even, "It is evil to destroy the world," is not something everyone agrees on (witness the willingness of nuclear-armed states to kill tens of millions of defenseless people, even at the cost of the Earth's surface; or then a similar willingness on the part of corporate states to despoil that surface (and some of the underground)).

Comment: @KristianBerry Maybe we could get the majority to agree to prevail on the others?

Comment: @ScottRowe, one might argue that we *have* achieved this to an extent. Most all of us knew that COVID-19 was not a Captain Tripps kind of scenario, but we cared about the elderly and people with compromised health, and rather than sacrifice those people just to keep the corporate machine going smoothly, we agreed to the fight. Granted, an insane cult decided to go against us all on this point, but as for majority agreement, well... And I doubt most civilians (or even soldiers) actually believe that nuclear holocaust is permissible (nevermind conditionally obligatory!).

Answer (score 3):

"You acted wrongly in stealing that money" could be interpreted as:

1. You stole that money.
2. A reasonable, fully-informed person would prefer to live in a society with a social norm such that those who steal money in the manner that you did are chastised and punished.
3. You broke that norm.

The notion of a "reasonable, fully-informed person" is central. This is a hypothetical person whose methods of thought the speaker approves of ("reasonable"), and who has been given all the relevant facts and all the time necessary to come to a conclusion on the matter ("fully-informed").

It is by the notion of a "reasonable, fully-informed person" that we avoid pure subjectivity; the speaker is not claiming just that he (the speaker) doesn't like you stealing the money, but that an ideal thinker wouldn't like it either. In this way, two people may have sincere disagreements on a moral matter, if they disagree on what the "reasonable, fully-informed person" would say. None of us qualify as "fully-informed" in this sense - but we might be able to agree on what "reasonable" means, and then speculate (and disagree) on what a reasonable person would eventually conclude if they became fully informed.

Comment: I'm going out to search for these people. Let's see, where is my lamp? (Diogenes)

Comment: I like that approach! It sounds like it mixes a little bit of the "what would a virtuous person do" from virtue ethics with the universality of Kant's categorical imperative. Thank you! I am taking a minor in philosophy and am very much enjoying expanding my knowledge.